# Connect to MS Access database through SSH from C# application

Tags: c#, ms-access, amazon-ec2, database-connection

Is it possible to connect to a MS Access database on a Windows 2022 EC2 instance from a serverless C# web api in the same AWS account through SSH or another means? I have made sure the MS Access drivers are installed on the EC2 as well as OpenSSH Client and Server.

I am able to access the EC2 instance and see the database file from my C# application using OpenSSH and the SSH.Net library when testing on my local machine, but I am not sure how I can setup the connection string for the database. Once connected to the server via SSH, is there a way to connect to the database? Or if not, is there a different way to connect to the database on the remote server?

When I look at https://www.connectionstrings.com/access/ it seems to only refer to connecting to a shared network. So if I login to the EC2 and share the database folder, would I be able to connect that way once the web api is deployed to AWS?

My database connection code which does not work is:

```
            string host = "EC2IPAddress";
            string sharedEC2FolderAndFile = @"//EC2AMAZ-#######/Users/DBAccessUser/DbFiles/MyAccessDb.mdb";
            string username = "EC2UserName";
            string password = "EC2Password";
            //string conn = "Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};Dbq=" + host;
            string conn = "Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};Dbq=" + sharedEC2FolderAndFile;

            using (var connection = new OdbcConnection(conn))
            {
                try
                {
                    connection.Open();
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {

                    throw;
                }
                finally
                {
                    connection.Close();
                }
            }
```

My SSH code that reads the file and does work is like this:

```
var client = new SftpClient(sftpConfiguration.Host, sftpConfiguration.Port, sftpConfiguration.Username, sftpConfiguration.Password);
            using (client)
            {
                try
                {
                    client.Connect();
                    string workingDirectory = client.WorkingDirectory + "/TestDirectory";
                    var files = client.ListDirectory(workingDirectory);

                    foreach (var file in files)
                    {
                        // Do something here.
                        // The MS Access database shows as it should
                    }
                    return files;
                }
                catch (Exception exception)
                {
                    client.Disconnect();
                    logger.LogError(exception, $"Failed in listing files under [{sftpConfiguration.RemotePath}]");
                    return null;
                }
                finally
                {
                    client.Disconnect();
                }
            }
```

Comment: _Or if not, is there a different way to connect to the database on the remote server?_ Yes, develop a web service offering rest-api access to your database.

Comment: The only multi-user scenario that is supported for Access is using a local SMB server with a stable network connection and file leasing turned off. The Access Database Engine is not stateless and explicitly does not support use for server applications, though your mileage may vary. Practically, a solid low-latency VPN connection + SMB server can do the trick

Comment: So if I were to go the route of web service that offers rest APIs to connect to my database, would that be a .net application which gets deployed to the same EC2 instance that the Access database resides on? Then I would have my separate web APIs deployed serverlessly call those API end points from the web service on that EC2?